# Get facebook friends list in js api

Tags: javascript, facebook, jsapi

```
I am getting user info but unable to get friend list.    

<script>
    function sortMethod(a, b) {
        var x = a.name.toLowerCase();
        var y = b.name.toLowerCase();
        return ((x < y) ? -1 : ((x > y) ? 1 : 0));
    }

    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({ appId: 'xxxxxxxxx', 
            status: true, 
            cookie: true,
            xfbml: true,
            oauth: true
        });

        function updateButton(response) {
            var button = document.getElementById('fb-auth');

            if (response.authResponse) { // in case if we are logged in
                var userInfo = document.getElementById('user-info');
                FB.api('/me', function(response) {
                    userInfo.innerHTML = '<img src="https://graph.facebook.com/' + response.id + '/picture">' + response.name;
                    button.innerHTML = 'Logout';
                });

                // get friends
                FB.api('/me/invitable_friends', function(response) {
                    var result_holder = document.getElementById('result_friends');
                    var friend_data = response.data.sort(sortMethod);

                    var results = '';
                    for (var i = 0; i < friend_data.length; i++) {
                        results += '<div><img src="https://graph.facebook.com/' + friend_data[i].id + '/picture">' + friend_data[i].name + '</div>';
                    }

                    // and display them at our holder element
                    result_holder.innerHTML = '<h2>Result list of your friends:</h2>' + results;
                });

                button.onclick = function() {
                    FB.logout(function(response) {
                        window.location.reload();
                    });
                };
            } else { // otherwise - dispay login button
                button.onclick = function() {
                    FB.login(function(response) {
                        if (response.authResponse) {
                            window.location.reload();
                        }
                    }, {scope:'email'});
                }
            }
        }

        // run once with current status and whenever the status changes
        FB.getLoginStatus(updateButton);
        FB.Event.subscribe('auth.statusChange', updateButton);    
    };

    (function() {
        var e = document.createElement('script'); e.async = true;
        e.src = document.location.protocol + '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
        document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
    }());
    </script>
```

user getting logged in but
Unable to display facebook friends list.

Code was working before new sdk.
using invitable_friends before it was me/friends.

anyone please help.

and also is there any way besides this ?

Comment: What do you need the list of friends for? With API v2, you only get a user’s friends that are also using the same app. And `invitable_friends` is for use by canvas apps in the Games category only; if you’re app isn’t in that category, then don’t misuse `invitable_friends` for anything else.

Comment: I am making simple app just unable to get friends list.

Answer (score 3):

You need to ask for `user_friends` in the authorization process:

```
FB.login(function(response) {
    if (response.authResponse) {
        window.location.reload();
    }
}, {scope:'email,user_friends'});
```

You need this both for `/me/friends` and for `/me/invitable_friends`, see Facebook docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/invitable-friends/v2.1

Although you will only get friends who are using the App too with `/me/friends`. See changelog for more information: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog

What CBroe commented in your question is very important too. `invitable_friends` is for Games on facebook.com only.

Answer (score 0):

If your app is public and live also some of the friends who are using the app then  you can get the list of them.

See what the documentation state [#reference-user_friends](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/#reference-user_friends):

**user_friends** - *Provides access to a person's list of friends that also use your app.*

After that you will be able to see what you want.

```
FB.api('/me/friends', function(response){
    console.log(response);
}, {scope: 'user_friends'});
```